# ListView.builder bottom overflow by pixel in flutter

Tags: android, dart, flutter

This is how I'm using `ListView.builder`  and it is taken in `Column` with `Expanded` widgets. I have tried some solution but they are not working and this is a dynamic list.

```
return Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          headingContainer(width,order_response),
          Expanded(
            child:  ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              controller: _scrollController,
              itemCount:order_response.orderDetails.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, position) {return orderListItemTile(width,height,order_response,position);},
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
```

[image]
This is my item Widget

```
 Column orderListItemTile(double width,double height, Order order_response, int position){
      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new OrderDetails(payload:order_response.orderDetails[position].orderRowId)),
              );
            },
            child: new  Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: MyColors.backgroundColor),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:width*0.05,right: width*0.05,top:width*0.03,bottom: width*0.03),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(order_response.orderDetails[position].orderDateTime,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 14.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
                SizedBox(height: height*0.01),
                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(order_response.orderDetails[position].productName,style: TextStyle(color: MyColors.colorPrimaryDark,fontSize: 18.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 26.0,
                      width: 26.0,
                      child: RawMaterialButton(
                        onPressed: () {

                        },
                        child: new Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 16.0,
                        ),
                        shape: new CircleBorder(),
                        elevation: 2.0,
                        fillColor: Colors.grey[400],
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: height*0.01),
                Text(order_response.orderDetails[position].customerName,style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey,fontSize: 14.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w800)),
              ],
            ),
          ),),
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey[350]),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:width*0.05,right: width*0.05),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 36.0,
                        width: 36.0,
                        child: IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:4.0,bottom: 4.0),
                            icon: Image.asset(order_response.orderDetails[position].orderStatus.contains('accepted')?'assets/images/right.png':'assets/images/wrong.png'),
                            onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context,true);}
                        )),
                    SizedBox(
                        height: 36.0,
                        width: 36.0,
                        child: IconButton(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:4.0,bottom: 4.0,left: 5.0),
                            icon: Image.asset('assets/images/cart.png'),
                            onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context,true);}
                        )),
                  ],),
                Text('Total ${order_response.orderDetails[position].orderAmount}',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87,fontSize: 16.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w700)),

              ],),)

        ],
      );
    }
```

Comment: Do you have any item after - `ListView.builder`  in `Column`?

Comment: no, I don't have any item below `listview`.

Comment: @anmol.majhail i have taken `listview` inside colum, it may create problem?

Comment: @anmol.majhail I tried it without column then it is working but how can I use header over listview?

Comment: It should work - i tried your code - worked fine. make sure you don't have element under List view as list view is expanded to cover up the rest of screen.

Comment: @anmol.majhail   I reinstall the app again, now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wrap Container with SingleChildScrollView

Comment: I tried with `SingleChildScrollView` but it was showing error.

Comment: in my case, i use SingleChildScrollView at :

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('Setting'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.orange,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView ( child : Column .....

Answer (score 0):

Try to give your Container full height like `height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height`