# How to solve ListView.builder bottom overflow issue?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having the same issue that is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54688080/listview-builder-bottom-overflow-by-pixel-in-flutter). I've tried all of the solutions provided and I'm still getting an error "RenderFlex overflowed by x pixels on the bottom". I don't have any widgets underneath the [custom](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_pagewise) ListView Builder. I'm really at a loss here.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    new GradientAppBar("Twitter"),
    new Container(
      child: Flexible(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 10.0),
              child: UserInfoHeader(userinfo)
            ),
            PagewiseListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              pageSize: 200,
              itemBuilder: (context, TwitterCardContent entry, _) {
                return TwitterCard(entry);
              },
              pageFuture: (pageIndex) {
                return getStatuses(userinfo.screenName);
              },
            )
          ],
        ),
      ), 
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

And here is the contents of each List item.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Card(
  //elevation: 8.0,
  margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
  child: Container(
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0)
    ),
    child: ListTile(
      contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 10.0),
      leading: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12.0),
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
          border: new Border(
            right: new BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white54)
          )
        ),
        child: notchecked,
      ),
      title: Text(
        statusCard.timeStampString,
        style: Theme.TextStyles.buttonText,
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        statusCard.text,
        style: Theme.TextStyles.contentCardText,
      ),
      trailing: delete,
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your first column with SingleChildScrollView?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Column` widget doesn't scroll and you have that widget as your parent widget and `PageListView` as a child inside it.
Instead, replace your parent `Column` widget with `ListView` that should resolve renderflow exception.

Comment: Thanks @DK15, replacing the parent widget with ListView worked. I also had to move the UserInfoHeader widget to the appbar.

Comment: You can wrap the "Column" inside a "SingleChildScrollView" and it should fix it

Answer (score 12):

Wrap your listview builder with expanded widget.

Comment: Please, add some example for help him.

Answer (score 11):

just to add an example to Dave's answer

```
   Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 5,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container();
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that your ListView is inside a **Column** which has fixed height and can't be scroll whereas listview scrolls. I am not sure but changing Column a **listview** itself or using Expanded/Flexible with Column could workOut.